# Gmail uses both DKIM and DomainKeys, while Hotmail uses none?

Tags: dkim, domainkeys

I noticed that Gmail messages have both a DKIM-Signature header and a DomainKey-Signature header, while Hotmail messages have none.

1. What is the purpose of using both
   DKIM and DomainKey signatures, as
   Gmail does?
2. Is it fairly safe/compliant to use only DKIM, and
   not DomainKeys?
3. How come Hotmail doesn't use any of these methods?

I'm sorry for combining a few questions under one: they don't seem to warrant individual entries.

Thanks!

Comment: Googling those terms will quickly bring up the Wikipedia entries for [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) and [DomainKeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys)

Answer (score 2):

1. For additional authenticity verification.
2. If you're going to take the time to set one up, why not do both?
3. Ask them.

Comment: DKIM "replaced" DomainKeys, almost nobody still uses DomainKeys. Very few places use DKIM either. [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) is much more popular and doesn't have all the problems DKIM does.

Comment: @Chris S, Care to elaborate on the problems DKIM has?

Comment: I too am interested in hearing about DKIM's problems. I've run it without issue for years now. SPF is complementary to, rather than a replacement for, DKIM. You should be using both.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is backing [Sender ID](http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/technologies/senderid/default.mspx)  - http://mail.live.com/mail/policies.aspx